# Adobe CQ - Specify where JCR content is written (exact path)

Tags: java, aem, jcr

I am trying to create a dialog that has an xtype of "textfield"...I need to specify that anytime the user updates this field it will always overwrite the same JCR content node.

I am including this component/dialog in multiple pages, so that the author can edit the text. The issue is that the text will be updated for that page. (because I am using a relative path).

What I need to happen...The content is updated and written to a central location so that no matter which page the user edits this text it will always update to a central location.

A real world example:
We have modal dialogs that show throughout the site. Some of these dialogs are global. Out client has requested to have an edit option on any page that these dialogs show. The acceptance criteria is that they can edit on any page and that edit will be applied globally.

My problem is that I am not sure how to set the path that the text field will write to.

I am retrieving the content from here:

```
 <cq:include path="/content/jjj/en/misc/deviceoutmodal/jcr:content/buttontext1" resourceType="zig/components/text"/>
```

How can I write to the same path?

Comment: Is it not writing back to that same path? The path is the path to the content for the component. This path is where values entered in the dialog are stored.

Comment: So if I were to setup the xtype what properties would I need to use to save to the above path? Would I need to change the "name" property? Sorry...still new to CQ.

Comment: You should need to do anything different because you pull the component in that is on the other page everything will already point to the correct path. The name property for the xtype is typically a relative path to the path of the component which you set with the path attribute of the cq:include tag.

Answer (score 1):

I think this would be best achieved with design dialogs — you can set a property based on the component (or template), which will then get used by every instance of that component.

The editor can edit the property when in Design mode, (or through the Designer as far as I remember). Design dialogs are created like regular dialogs but named `design_dialog.xml`. The [example use-case](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/developing/components.html#Logo%20Component) that Adobe lists is for a logo component:

> The Logo component displays the logo of the website Geometrixx. The
>   logo image and the home link can be configured globally (same for
>   every page of the website) so that every instance of this component is
>   identical. Therefore a design dialog is needed to provide the image
>   and path of the home link to the design of the corresponding Page. The
>   Logo component is placed in the upper left corner of all pages on the
>   website.

Comment: Seems odd that I can't specify the location content is stored.

Comment: You could probably tap into the JCR API directly & write something that would allow for that, but generally for these types of requirements I think OOTB (via design dialogs, reference components or iparsys) will give you the best trade-off between the amount of custom code you'll need to write & the UX for your editors.

Comment: So I would only need to change:  
jcr:primaryType
Name
cq:Dialog

to:
 
jcr:primaryType
Name
cq:design_dialog.xml

Comment: You can keep the jcr:primaryType as `cq:Dialog`, though the file name itself would need to change from dialog.xml to design_dialog.xml (If you use CRXDE, I think it has an option in the context menu for creating design dialogs).